# Were there any changes to aggro mechanics in WoD

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I haven't played much WoW since Cataclysm, so I'm not sure if anything has changed. I rolled a Resto Druid a couple of weeks ago, and in every dungeon I'm queued for I have found myself pulling all aggro off of the tanks. At first I thought that maybe it was just a couple of bad tanks, but it has been every single one that I have encountered.

It has gotten to the point where I nearly have to let the group wipe before I start healing in order to keep the aggro on the tank.

Is this typical? Do healing spells now generate significantly more aggro? Or has every one of the last 60 dungeons I've encountered just had a tank that wasn't as effective as I remember?

Comment: Do you cast thorns on your tanks? It's a minor threat benefit for them, but it could matter. Also try downloading a threat meter to see exactly how much more threat you generate than your tank.

Comment: Makes me wonder if this is an unintended side effect of Blizzard lowering all damage, health, and armor levels.  Still, you'd think shrinking all the numbers equally...

Comment: This has not been my experience in WoD content.  What level are you (because the answer may be different at different levels)?

Comment: And how exactly are you healing the encounters?

Comment: @Troyen Level 57 currently on this toon.
MichaelHampton I'm not sure what you mean. It's been a while since I played last, so I've been playing it safe. All members have Rejuvenation on them, tank also has Regrowth. I also have another HoT spell on the tank, I just can't recall the name at the moment. It may be a talent. I focus on the tank, casting Healing Touch, whenever possible (slow cheap heal). When more damage comes in, I spam Regrowth, and when that still doesn't cut it, I have an "Oh Shit" macro that casts Nature's Swiftness, Healing Touch, and Swiftmend.

Comment: @Zymus, It has been a while since I've played a resto druid but it doesn't sound like you are doing anything inherently wrong but you can checkout www.icy-veins.com or www.noxxic.com for suggestions on rotation/priority list

Comment: @Dispensador - Thorns was removed in MoP

Comment: @EkoostikMartin That shows how long it's been since I last played.

Comment: Level 57? I just recently leveled a warrior tank through 60, so you're actually not too far off from what I've been doing. IMO there shouldn't be any major threat issues for warrior or pally (dunno about druids) as we already have plenty of AoE by this time. One thing to note is that this is the level range where dungeons tend to have plenty of mob packs near to each other. If a tank taunts a mob and then you heal right after, you'll get threat. Best advice I can give is to stack on the tank,that way he can pull everything off you real quick like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were no threat mechanic changes in WoD that would have caused the problem you mention. In fact threat generation was [significantly buffed](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/blog/15682579/#vengeance) (thanks Troyen for the link) for tanks.

You did mention in the comments that you are currently level 57 and with that in mind it is important to note that the game designers do not balance the classes and mechanics too heavily at anything but max level.

That being said I would say this is likely just caused by inexperienced tanks not being able to hold threat on multiple targets (I know some tank specs get their best aoe abilities pretty late).

I would also say that as long as your gear is up to par it shouldn't be an issue* just keep healing and stay near the tank so he can taunt anything you pull back.

*Once you get closer to max level this will no longer be the case.

Comment: As a matter of fact, they buffed threat on tanks.  [All tanking stances and similar effects now increases threat generated by 900% (up from 600%)](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/blog/15682579/#vengeance), but it may not have scaled well.

Comment: Good to know, I will amend my answer.